# Jetty session clustering using jetty-maven-plugin

Tags: java, webserver, jetty, embedded-jetty, maven-jetty-plugin

I'm trying to set up session clustering using [this](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Feature/Session_Clustering_Using_a_Database)

My jetty.xml:

```
....
<Set name="sessionIdManager">
    <New id="jdbcIdMgr" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.JDBCSessionIdManager">
        <Arg>
            <Ref id="Server"/>
        </Arg>
        <Set name="workerName"><Property name="jetty.jdbcSession.workerName" default="node1"/></Set>
        <Set name="scavengeInterval"><Property name="jetty.jdbcSession.scavenge" default="1800"/></Set>

        <Call name="setDriverInfo">
            <Arg><Property name="jetty.jdbcSession.driverClass"
                           default="com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource"/></Arg>
            <Arg><Property name="jetty.jdbcSession.connectionURL"
                           default="jdbc:mysql://${datasource.dbServerName}:${datasource.dbServerPort}/${datasource.dbName}"/></Arg>
        </Call>
    </New>
</Set>
.....
```

My jetty-web.xml :

```
<Get name="Server">
        <Get id="jdbcIdMgr" name="sessionIdManager"/>
    </Get>

    <Set name="sessionHandler">
        <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler">
            <Arg>
                <New id="jdbcmgr" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.JDBCSessionManager">
                    <Set name="idManager">
                        <Ref id="jdbcIdMgr"/>
                    </Set>
                </New>
            </Arg>
        </New>
    </Set>
```

The problem is that I'm getting NPE during server startup, because Server instance is not set to my WebAppContext instance so I can't get my sessionIdManager using :

```
<Get name="Server">
    <Get id="jdbcIdMgr" name="sessionIdManager"/>
</Get>
```

I looked at jetty-maven plugin sources and found that at first it configures my WebAppContext instance and then in calls setServer:

```
    //set up the webapp and any context provided
    this.server.configureHandlers();
    configureWebApplication();
    this.server.addWebApplication(webApp);
```

How can I properly set up my session clustering stuff?

Comment: You are vastly abusing the role of `jetty-maven-plugin` (for testing simple webapps).  You might be better off making your project a formal `${jetty.base}` by adding a `start.ini` configured for your instance.

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt We already have a bunch of apps configured for using jetty-maven plugin. It will be a bit expensive to reconfigure all the stuff. I posted the solution I found below. Is it acceptable?

Answer (score 0):

After digging in the sources I extended JDBCSessionManager class, where I set _sessionIdManager property:

```
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.HashSessionIdManager;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.JDBCSessionManager;

public class ScoopSessionManager extends JDBCSessionManager {

    @Override
    public void doStart() throws Exception {
        final Server server = getSessionHandler().getServer();
        _sessionIdManager = server.getSessionIdManager();
        if (_sessionIdManager == null) {
            _sessionIdManager = new HashSessionIdManager();
            server.setSessionIdManager(_sessionIdManager);
        }
        super.doStart();
    }
}
```

Seems to be working now.

Comment: This is a hack to avoid using Jetty correctly.  `jetty-maven-plugin` is not meant to for running a production server.  **It is dangerous**.  You have all of Jetty, all of Maven, all of its plugins, all of your project dependencies on the server classpath at the same time, and then again in the WebAppClassLoader. Often with conflicting behavior and who knows how many vulnerabilities.  Would strongly encourage you to use Jetty properly for production.

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt Thanks for the advice! We will think about it.